# (Javascript) SlideShow Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello fellow stackoverflow members,
I've been trying to make a Slideshow. I've referenced from many other sites including this one but the pictures aren't showing up in the container element nor are the "prev" and "next" buttons functioning properly. I'd appreciate it if I got help! :)

my code:

```
var photos = newArray ();
    photos[0] = "img/image(2).jpg";
    photos[1] =  "img/image(4).jpg";
    photos[2] = "img/image(6).jpg";
    photos[3] = "img/image(8).jpg";
    photos[4] = "img/image(10).jpg";
    photos[5] = "img/image(12).jpg";
    photos[6] = "img/image(14).jpg";
    photos[7] = "img/image(16).jpg";
    photos[8] = "img/image(18).jpg";
    photos[9] = "img/image(20).jpg";
    photos[10] = "img/image(22).jpg";
    photos[11] = "img/image(24).jpg"
    //END OF PHOTOS ARRAY//
var i = 0;
var k = photos.length-1;
function next.onclick() {
var img= document.getElementById("image-container");
img.src = photos[i];
if (i < k ) {
    i++;
}else {
i = 0; }

} 
function prev.onclick() {
var img= document.getElementById("image-container");
img.src=photos[i];
if)i > 0) {i--;}
else {i = k; }
}
getImageArray = function(containerId) {
    var containerElement = document.getElementById(container);
    if (containerElement) {
        var imageArray = containerElement.getElementById("container");
        return photos[i];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

this is what my slideshow looks like (it's broken)
http://prntscr.com/5dcfzq
The share button isn't important, I can make that work at least.
The main problem is that the pictures aren't showing and the back and foward buttons are messed up :'(

p.s ( I'm not sure if part of the reason is how I'm linking to the "next" or "back" functions with the div tag, because i'm this is how i'm doing it :

```
<div id = "back" onclick = "prev()"></div>
```

Comment: `var photos = newArray ();` There needs to be a space between new and Array, to start with (so `var photos = new Array();`)

Comment: `function prev.onclick() {` needs to be just `function prev() {`; same with 'next.onclick()' based on usage in HTML.

Comment: in `prev()` ... `if)i > 0) {i--;}` should be `if (i > 0) { i--; }`

Comment: Do you have a reason to roll your own slideshow? There's tons of stuff out there you could reuse like this: http://www.slidesjs.com/ for one.

Comment: in 'prev()', else should be i = k-1;

Comment: Not sure why you have the getImageArray ...

Comment: this assumes there is an `<img id="image-container" />` tag in the HTML

Comment: thank you guys :),  also @Paul Sasik, I'm pretty new to Javascript and the slideshow is a school project.

Comment: also, @rfornal, if not "getImageArray" what should I use for the pictures to show up? now i have this  "function container(container) {"

Comment: When you attach the image information from the array into image source (`img.src = photos[i];`), the image "should" load.  Sorry, been up for 26+ hours ... it's getting fuzzy.  I'll look for comments on how it's working in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

OK ... to summarize ...

**1.** `var photos = newArray ();`

- There needs to be a space between new and Array, so ...

  var photos = new Array();

**2.** `function prev.onclick() {` needs to be just `function prev() {`

**3.** Same with `next.onclick()` based on usage in HTML.

**4.** In `prev()` ... `if)i > 0) {i--;}` should be ...

```
if (i > 0) { i--; }
```

**5.** **WRONG:** Also in `prev()' ... else should be`i = k-1;`

**6.** **DO NOT NEED** Not sure why you have the getImageArray function at all.

**7.** This assumes there is an '' tag in the HTML.

**UPDATE**:

Here's the code that works ... this all goes in the body:

These are my assumptions in the body ...

```
<img id="image-container" />
<div id="back" onclick="prev()">Previous</div>
<div id="next" onclick="mext()">Next</div>
```

The script code MUST be at the end of the body ...

```
<script>
    var photos = new Array ();
        photos[0] = "img/image(2).jpg";
        photos[1] =  "img/image(4).jpg";
        photos[2] = "img/image(6).jpg";
        photos[3] = "img/image(8).jpg";
        photos[4] = "img/image(10).jpg";
        photos[5] = "img/image(12).jpg";
        photos[6] = "img/image(14).jpg";
        photos[7] = "img/image(16).jpg";
        photos[8] = "img/image(18).jpg";
        photos[9] = "img/image(20).jpg";
        photos[10] = "img/image(22).jpg";
        photos[11] = "img/image(24).jpg"
        //END OF PHOTOS ARRAY//

    // Here, I set the img variable so that it can be re-used.
    // I also loaded the first image ...
    var i = 0;
    var k = photos.length-1;
    var img = document.getElementById("image-container");
    img.src = photos[i];

    function next() {
        img.src = photos[i];
        if (i<k) {
            i++;
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
    } 
    function prev() {
        img.src=photos[i];
        if (i>0) {
            i--;
        } else {
            i = k;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Haven't tested this, but leave a note here if it's still not working and I'll create something to test it further.

Comment: I removed the getimagearray function, but the buttons still aren't working, and I'm not sure why. http://prntscr.com/5dcmmh << thats how the onclick code in HTML looks like. Also, the pictures aren't sized the same so do I use the "max-height/width" property in the CSS or do i give it a set height and width?

Comment: now there is a random white box http://prntscr.com/5dcr8t oo I understand why this appeared, it's because i set the the containerid for the images minimum height/width to "100px", but i did this so the div could resize itself to fit the picture. :/ this is making no sense

Comment: working code is now posted.  I verified the operation of this code.

Comment: Glad I could assist. I've worked with several versions of scripts like this ... some better than others.